# R one-liner for reversing nesting order of a list?

Tags: r

Is there a concise R "one-liner" or an existing function to reverse the nesting order of a list? That means element `list[[i]][[j]]` in the input will map to `list[[j]][[i]]` in the output.

For example,

```
my_input <- list(list(1,2,3), list('a','b','c'), list('foo','bar','baz'))

desired_output <- list(list(1,'a','foo'), list(2,'b','bar'), list(3,'c','baz'))
```

Comment: @slava-kohut thanks for flagging as dupe, I didn't realize transpose was the correct term

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**1)** `transpose` in the purrr package does that:

```
library(purrr)
transpose(my_input)
```

**2)** this also works and uses no packages:

```
n <- length(my_input[[1]])
split(simplify2array(my_input), 1:n)
```

**2a)** It could also be written as:

```
s <- simplify2array(my_input)
split(s, 1:nrow(s))
```

**3)** This is another approach:

```
split(do.call("c", my_input), sequence(lengths(my_input)))
```

**4)** Here is an approach that does not use `split`:

```
as.list(as.data.frame(t(simplify2array(my_input))))
```

Comment: Have added n to code.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way, using `lapply` and `sapply`:

```
lapply(1:length(my_input[[1]]), FUN = function(i) sapply(my_input, FUN = function(x) x[i]))
```

In the `lapply`, you're looping over the length of the items within a sub-list, `sapply` is looping over the entire list.